# Get message from other modules

Tags: erlang

I am working on a logger module which stores text in a file. In this logger file Im trying to receive message from other modules in the same project. I have a controller that has a few outputs that is written to the shell. I don't want this output to be written to the shell instead i want this output to be able to send it to my logger module, and that module should afterwards write the output to a file.

The question is how should I write the code to receive this messages?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an OTP application? If so, D.Nibons answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Basically without any further detailed information I would think you want to create a [event handler (gen_event behaviour)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/events.html) which is ideal for situations as logging, event handling (hence the name :) and such.

Comment: If the environment isn't very stressed (the logger won't be hammered) then this can be one way of doing it and will suffice. If it is a very stressed environment it won't scale though so consider using an ETS table as a buffer and dump the content to a file on a regular basis. You risk loosing some log messages if you crash however so if this is not acceptable then you can solve that by having a priority one (that write straight) and one as buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you write code to receive any other message; with a `receive` block.